# Finitely Presented Modules Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am a little bit confused with the definition of finitely presented modules. In Lang's *Algebra* he defines a module $M$ to be finitely presented if and only if there is a exact sequence $F'\to F\to M \to 0$ such that both $F', F$ are free. However the standard definition I have seen elsewhere only demands $F'$ be finitely generated.  Are these two definitions equivalent?

Looking at the situation of a non-principal ideal of a ring, say $(x, y)$ of $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, it appears that this is finitely presented, by the usual definition, but I don't see any way of making it finitely presented by Lang's definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $F' \to F \to M \to 0$ is exact and $F'$ is finitely generated, choose some finitely generated free module $F''$ which maps *onto* $F'$. Then $F'' \to F \to M \to 0$ is exact.

This shows: A finitely generated module is finitely related iff it is finitely presented.

Of course, this fails for modules which are not finitely generated.

Comment: I don't get it: to which question answers this?

Comment: I prove that the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Which definitions: the wrong definition of finitely presented modules, and the definition of related modules? (I'm simply confused.)

Comment: Do you really refer to the trivial typo that Parakee forgot to add "finitely generated"???

Comment: So, the OP has made a "trivial typo" (???). Thus he has spoiled the definition of finitely presented modules. (The way he "defines" a finitely presented module is totally wrong, because for each module there is an exact sequence $F'\to F\to M\to 0$ with $F,F'$ free modules.) But then which definitions are you proving that are equivalent? (Finitely presented is equivalent to finitely related??? I don't think so!) Your answer has no meaning for me, and your comments didn't shed any light on the matter.

Comment: Add that $F$ is f.g. free if you want to.

Comment: Finitely generated finitely related modules are certainly finitely presented. This is what your answer is trying to say?

Comment: Yes, because this was exactly the question. Of course, you have to read "free" as "finitely generated free" in Parakee's question. Notice that many authors only consider such free modules. For example, in algebraic geometry, almost nobody speaks of "locally finite free sheaves".

Answer (score 6):

In Lang's *Algebra* he defines a module $M$ to be finitely presented if and only if there is an exact sequence $F'\to F\to M \to 0$ such that both $F', F$ are free *of finite rank*, and this is the definition of [finitely presented modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_module#Finitely_presented_module). (Note that for each module $M$ there is an exact sequence $F'\to F\to M\to 0$ with $F,F'$ free modules.)

"*However the standard definition I have seen elsewhere only demands $F'$ be finitely generated*." This is the definition of [finitely related modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_module#Finitely_presented_module).

"*Are these two definitions equivalent*?" In general they aren't: Let $M$ be a finitely presented module, and $L$ a free module which is not finitely generated. Then $M\oplus L$ is finitely related, but not finitely presented. However, if the module is finitely generated the two definitions coincide.

Answer (score 0):

In Lang's definition, both $F$ and $F'$ must be finitely generated (and free). This definition is equivalent to: ‘There exists a short exact sequence:
$$0\to K\to F\to M\to 0$$
such the $T$ is a finitely generated free module, and the  module of relations $K$ is finitely generated. It is equivalent because there is exists a surjective homomorphism from a *finitely generated* free module onto $K$.